# Use constexpr for optional configuration

Tags: c++, constexpr

Right now, I use something like the following to provide configuration to "sub-projects" within my code:

```
//_config.h
#ifndef _CONFIG_H
#define _CONFIG_H

#if defined(USE_CONFIG_H) && USE_CONFIG_H == 1
#include <config.h>
#endif

#ifndef CONFIG_OPTION_1
//Default value for CONFIG_OPTION_1 
#define CONFIG_OPTION_1 10
#endif

#ifndef CONFIG_OPTION_2
//Default value for CONFIG_OPTION_2
#define CONFIG_OPTION_2 20
#endif

#endif
```

That way I can include `_config.h` in my sub-project, use the configuration values, and "override" them if necessary be defining `USE_CONFIG_H` at compile time and placing `config.h` in the include path.

Now, I have been trying to convert over as much old C-style code as I can to take advantage of the safer alternatives in C++. Once of these is converting constants defined using macros into constexpr values. For example

```
constexpr unsigned int CONFIG_OPTION_1 = 10;
```

The problem I am having is, how do I replicate the same behavior I had with macros being able to conditionally override the default configuration values?

Comment: `#define _CONFIG_H` That identifier is reserved to the language implementation. By defining it, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. You should use another header guard.

Comment: @eerorika I didn't realize that, but I don't actually do that in any of my software; I just wrote it for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are the only way to make conditional compilation, so you cannot get rid of them entirely. But you can use the macro to initialise a variable:

```
constexpr unsigned int NON_MACRO_CONFIG_OPTION_1 = CONFIG_OPTION_1;
```

Thereby getting the benefits of types.

Comment: So essentially, I would use the type-safe constexpr throughout the code, and the only place that needs to touch the macros is the _config.h file as I have shown?